# Authentication Required Payment Failure

Tags: payment, braintree, authentication

We are getting an increasing number of payment failures through our ecommerce website due to "Authentication Required" Our customers' banks say the issue is not on their end and that the reason for the payment failure is due to the customer not being asked to go through a secure authentication process by our ecommerce website. Our Payment processor, Braintree sings a similar tune. Is there anything in the Braintree/Magento 2 integration that is failing? Our developer also seems to be at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the same behaviour with our Magento site / Braintree card processing.  Can I ask what version of Magento you are running?